# Exponential graphs in Python without using NumPy

Tags: python, matplotlib, exponential

I'm new to python and i am trying to plot 3 exponential functions on the same axis without using NumPy (not allowed). MatPlotLib, SymPy etc are allowed.

Question answered with broad answers below.

Code removed for privacy - this is not needed to understand the answers below as they are broad, or to answer any future questions on this topic

Comment: Can you add your trial code?

Comment: Since numpy is a dependency of matplotlib, you cannot plot anything with matplotlib without using numpy.

Comment: You can use Matplotlib to plot list of numbers, I advice you to start building a list `x`of _N+1_ _x_ points, evenly spaced between 0 and _x_* ... `dx = x_last/N` etc etc

Comment: You can only plot something when you replace `a, b, delta` with some real numbers.

Comment: Please give some values for `a, b, d and x*` suitable for testing.

Comment: Your error comes from f_r being an empty list.  Also, you should call plot only at the end of the for-loop. Now it is indented to be inside the for-loop.

Comment: Now you create `r` as just a list of integers.  You need `r` to be a list of floats in small steps.  For example `steps = 200; r = [i*x_star/steps for i in range(steps)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, and I hope that you can understand my scruples, I prefer to leave my answer as generic as possible while trying to help you.

If you cannot use [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/)<sup>1</sup>, you have to use the [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) module and old good lists.

You start importing `math` from the standard library and the `pyplot` module from [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/contents.html):

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

You decide the interval in which you plot your function and how many points you need for your plot

```
x_0, x_N = 0, 12
N =120
```

`N` is best intended as the number of intervals between N+1 points, so that we write

```
dx = (x_N-x_0)/N
```

Now we can say `x_i = x_0 + dx × i` but we have to store our results so that they are reusable.  It's now that we have to use a list and we have two options, ① start with an empty list and `append` to it all the `x_i` using a `for` loop

```
xs = []
for i in range(N+1): xs.append(x_0+dx*i)
```

and ② a list comprehension

```
xs = [ x_0+dx*i for i in range(N+1) ]
```

(the result is identical).

You now have fixed the problem of the abscissae, it's the turn of the ordinates; again, we can use the `append` or the list comprehension

```
ys = []
for i in range(N+1):
    x = xs[i]
    y = math.sin(x/3.805)
    ys.append(y)
```

or

```
ys = [ math.sin(xs[i]/3.805) for i in range(N+1) ]
```

Now you can plot the function

```
plt.plot(xs, ys, label='sin(%.3fx)'%(1/3.805))
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: a half sine]

(1) You cannot use Numpy but, but Matplotlib will use Numpy behind the scenes...
 The lists that you pass to `plt.plot` are *immediately* converted to Numpy arrays! and only later are processed by the complex machinery of the plotting module.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), Python's package for symbolic math. It first solves x* to be `log(delta/2)/a`. Then, for some given values, a plot is drawn.

Note that sympy has a very simplified plotting function, with limited control over legend placement etc. If you need more control, the function values need to be calculated in an array.

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, a, b

delta = symbols('delta', real=True)
x_star = symbols('x*', real=True)
f = exp(a*x)
g = -exp(a*x)
h = exp(a*x)*sin(b*x)
eq = Eq(delta, f.subs(x, x_star) - g.subs(x, x_star))
sol = solve(eq, x_star)  # [log(delta/2)/a]

values = {a: 0.5, b: 1.5, delta:4.0}
x_star = sol[0].subs(values)

p = plot(f.subs(values), g.subs(values), h.subs(values), (x, 0, x_star), 
         show=False, legend=True, ylabel='', ylim=(-2,3.5))
p[0].line_color = 'r'
p[1].line_color = 'g'
p[2].line_color = 'b'

p.show()
```

Resulting plot:
[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Does this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your version with some small adaptions to make it work. Note that matplotlib's plot functions work a little bit different than sympy's.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import exp, sin

a = 5.0
b = 10.0
d = 0.1

x_star = 6.0
#x_star =(1/a)*float((math.log1p(d/2)))#    #x* evenually needs to be in this form*#
print('x*= ',x_star)

steps = 200; r = [i*x_star/steps for i in range(steps)]  # similar to np.linspace

f_r = []
g_r = []
h_r = []
for x in r:
    y = exp(a*x)
    f = y
    f_r.append(f)
    print('f(x)= ',f)
    g = -1*y
    g_r.append(g)
    print('g(x)= ',g)
    h = y*sin(b*x)
    h_r.append(h)
    print('h(x)= ',h)

plt.plot(r, f_r, 'b--', linewidth=1, color='r', label='f(x)=exp(a*x)')
plt.plot(r, g_r, 'b--', linewidth=2, color='g', label='g(x)=-exp(a*x)')
plt.plot(r, h_r, 'b--', linewidth=3, color='b', label='h(x)=exp(a*x)*sin(b*x)')

plt.ylabel('values')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.legend(title='functions')
plt.show()
```